# ceilometer - meter for getting active tenants

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova, keystone, ceilometer

I need to know the possibility of getting the active tenants using the ceilometer meter.

To be more clear, We can use the meter "Instance" for getting the instance details, "volume" for getting the volume usage, "image" for getting image details.

Likewise, I need to know the possibility of getting the active tenants or just tenants with the help of the ceilometer meters.

Someone help we with the details on the same.

Atleast let me know how we can add the new ceilometer meter for the same.

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack project (aka tenant) has very limited information, `openstack project list --long -f json`:

```
[
  {
    "Description": "Bootstrap project for initializing the cloud.", 
    "Enabled": true, 
    "ID": "bdec7f905efb45739a274647c6be7665", 
    "Name": "admin"
  }
]
```

Ceilometer is a telemetry service, for resource like instance in Nova, volume in Cinder, floating ip in Neutron, there is a need to telemetry these resources because billing depends on these data.

However, project is not such kind of resource, we create a project just like we create an account (company one, not private one) in bank, all the billing, charging is through this account, but the account itself is not required for telemetry, when we disable or delete this project, all operations from this project is blocked.

PS: I'm not quite sure what you say about **active**, and your use case for collect project information

Comment: I just need to get the project ID, But I should be able to get the same from ceilometer. I need to know how I can get the same in ceilometer.

Comment: I can see that there is some meters available such as "identity.project.created" in ceilometer, So that I expected that there will be some meters exists now for listing the active projects.

Comment: This is just an sample/event converted from notification, you cannot rely on it to find which one is active or not, the right way is gather information at where you configure those project, for example, cloudkitty, or somewhere else